# Rename Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Is there an easy way to rename a Lightning component or at least change the label so that in Community Builder / Lightning Builder the desired component name shows up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is very simple. You can set a label attribute in the design resource